# Could you point me to the JLS section where it is specified that inherited methods will not act on subclasses re-defined variables?

Tags: java, inheritance

Could you point me to the JLS section where it is specified that inherited methods will not act on subclasses re-defined variables?

I.e. the output of the following code is "value is 3" and *not* "value is 5".

```
public class PlayGround {

  int value = 3;

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PlayGround.PlayGroundSon pg = new PlayGround().new PlayGroundSon();
    System.out.println("value is "+pg.getValue());
  }

  class PlayGroundSon extends PlayGround{
    int value = 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that is specified by omission: only methods can be overridden. Fields can only *hide* other fields: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3

Comment: This has nothing to do with what you're asking. The `getValue()` method is only defined in `PlayGround` whose `value` is set to 3.  When the method is invoked, it is going to the subclass first to try to resolve it. Since the method is not defined in the subclass, it will invoke the one in the super class.

Comment: Fields are not "overriden;" instead of `int value = 5;` one could have `String value = "5";` - nothing to do with `getValue`'s `int value`.

Comment: Try this:  `System.out.println("value is "+ pg.value);` You'll see that the program will output `5` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not "re-defined" `value`. You have created a completely separate field in `PlayGroundSon` that happens to have the same name.

You can only override methods. If you want the program to print `5` you will have to override the `getValue()` method. I have also changed the name of the variable in `PlayGroundSon` to emphasize that it is not the same as `value` in `PlayGround`.

```
public class PlayGround {

    int value = 3;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayGround.PlayGroundSon pg = new PlayGround().new PlayGroundSon();
        System.out.println("value is "+pg.getValue());
    }

    class PlayGroundSon extends PlayGround{

        int sonValue = 5;

        @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return sonValue;
        }
    }
}
```